# Prove if the set $C=$ {${q \sqrt2 \in \Bbb R | q \in \Bbb Q \cap(0, \sqrt2) }$} is bounded above, bounded below and find its supremum and infimum

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Prove if the set $C=\{q \sqrt2 \in \Bbb R | q \in \Bbb Q \cap(0, \sqrt2)\}$ is bounded above, bounded below and find its supremum and infimum. prove it

I know that the infimum is $0$, supremum $=2$. But firstly how can I prove this set is bounded

Does anybody can helpe to prove it?

Comment: If you want a { or } sign in LaTeX, you need a slash in front of it. For example: `$x, {y}, \{z\}$` turns into $x, {y}, \{z\}$. (I edited the question for you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your only question is how to prove that the set $C$ is bounded.

$$\begin{align}
q\in\Bbb Q\cap(0,\sqrt 2) &\implies 0<q<\sqrt 2 \\
 &\implies 0\sqrt 2 < q\sqrt 2<\sqrt 2\sqrt 2 \\
 &\implies 0 < q\sqrt 2<2
\end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$x\in C\implies 0<x<2$$

So $C$ is bounded by $0$ and $2$.